# update-manager crashes with undefined symbol (libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so)

Tags: 13.04, 12.10, 13.10

When I lauch the software updater from the App launcher's icon, 
it crashes, runing it from the command line shows what the error is :

I've been getting this since 12.10, and it's still present on 13.10

```
max@max-ubuntu:~$ update-manager 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._gi import _API, Repository
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._gi import _API, Repository
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyglib-gi-2.0-python2.7.so.0: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
max@max-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/607210/367990

Answer (score 2):

`update-manager` is a Python 3 application. However I suspect your `PYTHONPATH` contains directories referring to your Python 2 installation. The problematic one is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which causes the incompatible Python 2 version of the `apt` package to be picked up.

Try unsetting your `PYTHONPATH` or run as

```
PYTHONPATH= update-manager
```