# I can't open software updater and unity tweak tool on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, update-manager, python-2.7, dbus

I have a notification nearly every time I try to update. That note 'An error occurred while checking for updates => [TR Language] Güncellemeler denetlenirken bir sorun oluştu.'

I can't open software updater, languages, Unity tweak tool.

```
$ sudo unity-tweak-tool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 33, in <module>
    import UnityTweakTool
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import dbus, dbus.service
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 33, in <module>
    import UnityTweakTool
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import dbus, dbus.service
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

The following description is suggestions

Print `import sys` and `sys.path`

```
$ python
>> import sys
>> sys.path
''
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

`which python` and `python --version`:

```
~$ which python
/usr/bin/python

~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: That looks like a messed up Python installation. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dbus python-apt` and post whether it worked and eventually occurred error messages. You have to leave me a comment (@ByteCommander) once you edited your question to notify me. Thanks.

Comment: i tried but not change. Same errors @ByteCommander

Comment: Similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/420852/367990

Comment: Could you try and run `python` in a terminal and when the prompt `>>>` shows up, enter `import sys`, and then `sys.path`. Exit python with [Ctrl+D] and edit your question to add the output.

Comment: import sys run but sys.path isnt run. @ByteCommander



``
>>sys.path
''
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
``

Comment: That is the correct output. But please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/607210/edit) your question to provide such additional information. And please include every line python outputted (including the headline telling the version etc.). Unfortunately this seems to be a different issue than I had and I am not experienced with python, so I fear this is where I can't help you any further... :-( I'll try if I can ask an expert to look over your question.

Comment: Okey. i edited . Thanks for help :) @ByteCommander

Comment: Actually I thought that the python command would include more info. The outputs of `which python` and `python --version` could also be useful for future readers.

Comment: Add in my messages. @ByteCommander

Comment: *ByteCommander* Python is just showing where the problem is: It's not a python problem...  It's a dbus problem...  @rockbang26 What did you do before this started?  Do you have a system back-up?

Comment: sorry. I dont backup previously . so i dont restore :( @Fabby

Comment: I've added the tag "dbus".  Let's see if there is a dbus expert here on the site...  (give it 24 hours)

Comment: It looks like python3 is trying to import python2 packages to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the top of the backtrace you will notice that `UnityTweakTool` is a Python 3 library. However your `PYTHONPATH` contains a lot of directories referring to your Python 2 installation. The problematic one is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, which causes the incompatible Python 2 version of the `apt` package to be picked up.

Try unsetting your `PYTHONPATH` or run as

```
sudo PYTHONPATH= unity-tweak-tool
```